# The notation $G(\mathcal K)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the [notes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_Grassmannian) about affine Grassmannian. Let $\mathcal K = k((t))$ be the field of formal Laurent series over $k$, and by $\mathcal O = k[[t]]$ the ring of formal power series over $k$. By choosing a trivialization of $E$ over all of $Spec \mathcal O$, the set of $k$-points of $Gr_G$ is identified with the coset space $G(\mathcal K)/G(\mathcal O)$.

I don't understand much about the notation $G(\mathcal K)$. What are the elements in $G(\mathcal K)$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $G(-)$ is the functor of points of the algebraic group $G$. The general yoga of Grothendieck style algebraic geometry is that a space $X$ should be studied by looking at all the maps into from all spaces at once. More precisely, to each space $X$ (scheme or variety in this case but really this works in any category) we can associate a functor

$$
h_X : Sch_k^{op} \to Set \enspace \enspace \enspace h_X(T) = \operatorname{Hom}_{Sch_k}(T,X)
$$

which takes a $k$-scheme $T$ and gives the set of all morphisms $T \to X$. This is a contravariant functor because if we have an $f: T \to T'$, we get $f^*:h_X(T') \to  h_X(T)$ sending a morphism $u: T' \to X$ to the composition $u \circ f : T \to X$. It turns out that this functor $h_X$ is just as good as $X$ itself in a very precise sense. Yoneda's lemma (which holds in any category not just for schemes) says that $X$ is uniquely determined by $h_X$. Thus, often we can do geometry by just working with the functor $h_X$ instead of $X$ itself and so usually these two objects are just identified and we write $X(T)$ for $h_X(T)$.

Now if we have an algebraic group $G$, then its functor of points actually gives you a group $G(T)$ for every $T$. You get this just form the group structure on $G$. In fact you can show that $G$ is an algebraic group if and only if its functor of points is a functor to the category of groups. This is another example of how the functor of points completely determines the space.

Now, in your case, an affine Grassmanian is supposed to parametrize $G$-bundles on the disc that are trivial on the punctured disc, i.e., pairs $(E,\varphi)$ where $E$ is a $G$-bundle on the disc $D$ and $\varphi$ is an isomorphism of $E|_{D_0}$ with a trivial bundle where $D_0$ is the punctured disc. In algebraic geometry the disc is though of as the scheme corresponding to the ring $\mathcal{O} = k[[t]]$ since $\mathcal{O}$ is a local neighborhood of $0$ and takes the place of the disc. Then we obtain $\mathcal{K} = k((t))$ by localizing $\mathcal{O}$ at the prime ideal of functions vanishing at $0$ and so corresponds to the punctured disc in algebraic geometry. Therefore, what we want are $G$-bundles on $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}$ that are trivial on $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{K}$.

The idea is that on curves, i.e. Riemann surfaces, any bundle becomes trivial after puncturing enough points. Then if we look at a small enough open neighborhood, we only need to puncture one point to trivialize a bundle. So locally, we should have that any bundle on the small disc $\mathcal{O}$ is trivial on the punctured $\mathcal{K}$. Therefore we can rephrase our affine Grassmanian as parametrizing trivial $G$-bundles on $\mathcal{K}$ modulo trivial $G$-bundles on $\mathcal{O}$. You can argue that a trivialization of a $G$-bundle over $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is the same as a morphism $\operatorname{Spec}A \to G$ so that the set of trivial bundles on $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is the same as the set $G(\operatorname{Spec}A)$ which we will denote by $G(A)$. Then we see that intuitively, the affine Grassmanian should be $G(\mathcal{K})/G(\mathcal{O})$. This is very imprecise and making it precise takes some work. See for example http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~celliott/Affine_Grassmannian.pdf or http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/SeminarNotes/Oct13%28AffGr%29.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Following Wikipedia, the affine Grassmannian is defined for an algebraic group $G$ defined over a field $k$. Since $\mathcal{K}$ and $\mathcal{O}$ are $k$-algebras, you can look at the points of $G$ in $\mathcal{K}$ or $\mathcal{O}$ and these points are denoted by $G(\mathcal{K})$ and $G(\mathcal{O})$.

Maybe, aren't you familiar with the fact that an algebraic group over $k$ can be seen as a functor from the category of $k$-algebras to the category of groups ?

Answer (score 0):

The notation $G$ means an algebraic group. A good reference for this topic is Milne's notes ***[Algebraic Groups](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf)***.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why this short sentence almost 3 years later, when the question has already been answered?

Comment: Initially, I am thinking of writing down the entire definition, but I realized the question was asked long ago and LJR probably has figured out the answer. So I just write down this short sentence mentioning Milne's notes which is a good reference just in case LJR is still interested in the theory of algebraic groups.

Comment: okay. That seems reasonable